# Why can I not use the handle returned by `WTSVirtualChannelQuery`?

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

In an attempt to utilize RDP Dynamic Virtual Channels.  I am passing the result of `WTSVirtualChannelQuery` with `WTSVirtualFileHandle` to a `FileStream`, but it throws various exceptions.  Why?

Call:

```
public static FileStream Open(string channelName, WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION option = WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION.DYNAMIC)
{
    // Open
    SafeFileHandle pFile = null;
    using (var sfh = WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, channelName, option))
    {
        WtsAllocSafeHandle pBuffer = null;
        try
        {
            int cbReturned;
            if (!WTSVirtualChannelQuery(sfh, WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS.FileHandle, out pBuffer, out cbReturned)
                || cbReturned < IntPtr.Size)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            pFile = new SafeFileHandle(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pBuffer.DangerousGetHandle()), false);
        }
        finally
        {
            pBuffer?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // create
    return new FileStream(pFile, FileAccess.ReadWrite, bufferSize: 32 * 1024 * 1024, isAsync: true);
}
```

Exceptions:

```
System.ArgumentException: Handle does not support asynchronous operations.  The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened synchronously (that is, it was not opened for overlapped I/O).
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(SafeFileHandle handle, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync)
```

and

```
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.VerifyHandleIsSync()
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(SafeFileHandle handle, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle returned by `WTSVirtualChannelQuery` seems to become invalid as soon as `WTSFreeMemory` is called.  Call `DuplicateHandle` before calling `WTSFreeMemory` and use the duplicated handle.

```
public static FileStream Open(string channelName, WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION option = WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION.DYNAMIC)
{
    // Open
    SafeFileHandle pFile = null;
    using (var sfh = WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, channelName, option))
    {
        WtsAllocSafeHandle pBuffer = null;
        try
        {
            int cbReturned;
            if (!WTSVirtualChannelQuery(sfh, WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS.FileHandle, out pBuffer, out cbReturned)
                || cbReturned < IntPtr.Size)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            var pWtsFile = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pBuffer.DangerousGetHandle());
            if (!DuplicateHandle(
                GetCurrentProcess(), pWtsFile,
                GetCurrentProcess(), out pFile, 
                0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            pBuffer?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // create
    return new FileStream(pFile, FileAccess.ReadWrite, bufferSize: 32 * 1024 * 1024, isAsync: true);
}
```